# How to get speech-to-text working with an AIFF file

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to send in an AIFF base64 through the Google Speech-to-text framework however it seems to only work with WAV files.
The API tells me that I need to set the AudioEncoding to be of a specific type, but I'm not sure which would work with AIFF. I'd also need to set the sampleHertzRate which I'm not sure how to retrieve using Javascript. Can anyone help with this?

Here is my POST body:

```
{
    "config": {
        "encoding": "LINEAR16",
        "audioChannelCount": 1,
        "sampleRateHertz": 8000,
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "profanityFilter": "true",
        "speechContexts": [],
        "enableAutomaticPunctuation": true,
        "metadata": {
            "interactionType": "VOICE_COMMAND",
            "microphoneDistance": "NEARFIELD",
            "originalMediaType": "AUDIO",
            "recordingDeviceType": "SMARTPHONE",
            "recordingDeviceName": "iPhone"
        },
        "model": "command_and_search"
    },
    "audio": {
        "content": "$base64Audio"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The API tells me that I need to set the AudioEncoding to be of a
>   specific type

maybe you have a "data URI problem" [mdn MIME_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) and you need to attach the data: MIME type to your file? like this:

```
let base64AudioUrl = `data:audio/x-aiff; base64,${$base64Audio}`;
```

On wikipedia they define two MIME types for AIFF:
"audio/x-aiff" and "audio/aiff"

If you post your data from a form may be you need to add enctype :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```